# Beginner's SQL: How do I find a detached database?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm brand new to SQL and I'm practicing some queries with a DB.
I've now just detached the database using Tasks > Detach

Question 1: When I detach a file, I'm guessing it's saved to an MDF file? Where would I locate this file?

Question 2: When I create a new DB, where do the related files get saved? I'm assuming an MDF and an LDF set of files are created.

If it helps, here's my version info

> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1) - 10.0.2531.0 (X64)   Mar 29 2009 10:11:52   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can always look at the database properties in your Object Explorer in SQL Server Management Studio **before** detaching - the file(s) will not be moved or anything when detaching....

[image]

In the `Properties` dialog box, go to the `Files` section and to your right, the relevant info can be found:

[image]

Comment: is it possible to locate the database file after detach?

Comment: @Sakthivel: look at the Properties dialog *before* detaching - it shows where the `.mdf`, optional `.ndf` and `.ldf` files reside

Comment: @marc_s : So there is no possibilities get details of  database after detached . Right?

Comment: @Sakthivel: you can search your entire file system for the files..... but it's easier to check **before** detaching, where those files are!

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server databases *are* .mdf files. When you detach, the .mdf file is closed by the SQL Server process, but it exists from the moment you create the database. Just to be clear, there is no concept of "saving" in an SQL DBMS; at least, not in the sense you are suggesting. Every transaction you perform is permanently stored from the moment it is committed.

When creating the database, the dialog box shows a list of files that will be created. You may have to resize some of the columns and scroll horizontally to see the full path. You can also see this information by bringing up the database properties dialog.

The .ldf file is the transaction log. It plays a vital role in ensuring the permanency of committed transactions.

Comment: Thanks @Marcelo. I was able to locate the path by simply scrolling :)

Comment: `.MDF` for the primary data file group, `.LDF` for the log files - and possibly `.NDF` for additional data and index files.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so if you have **already detached** the database, and then realized that you are clueless where it is, you can do this trick.

1. Expand server, then on `Databases` click <kbd>Right Mouse</kbd> then choose `Attach...`
2. Click `Add...`
3. Then in the new window that opens will be a path to the directory where your detached database is (if you haven't navigated from default location earlier)

Also, the default location for MSSql databases is:

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\[YourSQLVersionGoesHere]\MSSQL\DATA`

[image]

[image]

Hope this saves you some time.